# STS4 Java Editor Delays - Classpath Notifications

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS 4.1.2 with Eclipse 4.10.0.

When I edit a .java file, after a few seconds my entire STS environment freezes (including menu items, etc). A few seconds later it resumes, and whatever I typed/deleted appears in the editor. It makes the program basically unusable for Java editing.

I switched on UI Responsiveness Monitoring and can see that when the delay begins, the following lines appear in the Error Log

```
Preparing classpath changed notification some.project.name
exists = true open = true => deleted = false
classpath=236 entries
executing callback sts4.classpath.QQTdTYfA some.project.name false 236
executing callback sts4.classpath.QQTdTYfA FAILED
```

I get several of these occurrences, with the number of entries (236 above) changing, e.g. 209, 168, and also the classpath suffix e.g. QQTdTYfA.

I receive at least 10 of these occurrences but I'm not sure how to expand the Error Log to show me more.

Even adding or deleting one character, e.g. a semi-colon at the end of a line, causes these multiple occurrences and the delay.

There is also this stack trace, output to the Error Log when the UI responsiveness monitoring is triggered:

```
Stack Trace
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(CompletableFuture.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3323)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1775)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.stop(LanguageServerWrapper.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.disconnect(LanguageServerWrapper.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.stop(LanguageServerWrapper.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.start(LanguageServerWrapper.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.LanguageServerWrapper.getInitializedServer(LanguageServerWrapper.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4e.DocumentContentSynchronizer.documentChanged(DocumentContentSynchronizer.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged2(AbstractDocument.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.fireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument.replace(SynchronizableDocument.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument.replace(SynchronizableDocument.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.projection.ProjectionTextStore.replace(ProjectionTextStore.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1098)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.projection.ProjectionDocument.replace(ProjectionDocument.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.DefaultDocumentAdapter.replaceTextRange(DefaultDocumentAdapter.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.modifyContent(StyledText.java:7390)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.sendKeyEvent(StyledText.java:8254)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.doContent(StyledText.java:2502)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKey(StyledText.java:6038)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKeyDown(StyledText.java:6069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.lambda$1(StyledText.java:5767)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText$$Lambda$329/1187280528.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1064)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1106)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1489)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4888)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4768)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4770)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3545)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$$Lambda$21/510207317.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

in STS 3, the same projects allow me to edit without issue.

Does anyone have experience of this issue and/or have any suggestions for a resolution?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/212

Comment: Looks like different issue to me. LSP4e seems to be blocking the UI thread. It shouldn't do that. You should check and/or file a bug with lsp4e to report that. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&component=IDE&product=lsp4e

Comment: Can you enable the streaming of the log output of the Spring Boot language server to the console view via the preferences? You can find that in `Preferences -> Language Server -> Spring Language Server`, then check the `Spring Boot` entry. This should show the log output of the language server in the console view and would be interested for further analysis of this. You can also disable the language server in the preferences altogether (switch it off for the java source content type), that avoids the language server altogether, but would also disable many of the useful features.

Comment: please file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues with as many details as possible, so we can dive into the details there

Comment: I've filed an issue as requested, looking forward to your findings, thanks. Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: I switched off the Java Source language server and this resolved the issue, many thanks. I don't use many of the Spring Boot features so I may not need this switched on but it would be interesting to see what comes of your investigation anyway.